# Cannot add any online account besides google

Tags: facebook, oauth

When I'm clicking on Facebook in Online accounts I get

> Could not load generic-oauth plugin, please check your installation

Searching this error has lead me no where. I have a problems with all other account types besides google (that one works). For example, I also get to hear

> Could not load empathy-accounts-plugin plugin, please check your installation

I have empathy installed:

> empathy is already the newest version (3.12.11-0ubuntu3).

Forceing `--reinstall` did not help. How can I get this any further?